# How do we add elements in an arrayList at specific positions?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the Question :
Given an integer A, generate a square matrix filled with elements from 1 to A2 in spiral order.

My Output when `A=3` : `[8 9 5] [8 9 5] [8 9 5]`

I am unable to find error in my code. Can anybody help me?
Here is my code :

```java
public class Solution {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> generateMatrix(int A) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(A, new ArrayList(Collections.nCopies(A, 0))));
        int r1, r2, c1, c2, dir, i, count;
        r1 = c1 = 0;
        r2 = c2 = A - 1;
        dir = 0;
        count = 1;
        while (r1 <= r2 && c1 <= c2) {
            if (dir == 0) {
                for (i = c1; i <= c2; i++) {
                    //System.out.println(r1+" "+i+" "+count);
                    arr.get(r1).set(i, count);
                    count++;
                }
                r1++;
                dir = 1;
            } else if (dir == 1) {
                for (i = r1; i <= r2; i++) {
                    //System.out.println(i+" "+c2+" "+count);
                    arr.get(i).set(c2, count);
                    count++;
                }
                c2--;
                dir = 2;
            } else if (dir == 2) {
                for (i = c2; i >= c1; i--) {
                    //System.out.println(r2+" "+i+" "+count);
                    arr.get(r2).set(i, count);
                    count++;
                }
                r2--;
                dir = 3;
            } else if (dir == 3) {
                for (i = r2; i >= r1; i--) {
                    //System.out.println(i+" "+c1+" "+count);
                    arr.get(i).set(c1, count);
                    count++;

                }
                c1++;
                dir = 0;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to _add_ elements a specific positions as per your title (i.e. not set/replace them) have a look at the `add(int, E)` method.

Comment: Also: `Collections.nCopies(A, new ArrayList(...))` is a problem as this will return an immutable list and each element will be the _same_ instance of the array list. You need new array lists at each position of the outer one, e.g. by using a loop or streams.

Comment: No, I meant when the ArrayList is empty. For example, If  I wish to add a element at 4th position, It throws an error.

Comment: Do you want us to guess the error?

Comment: You can't add randomly to a List. You can only insert before the end or add at the end.
So either initialize your List with enough elements beforehand or use a Map or an array.